# Magento: Find observers for dispatched events?

Tags: events, magento, hook, observer-pattern

I need to find which methods fire when the following event is dispatched

```
   Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_add_item', array('quote_item' => $item));
```

I know how to create custom event hook and that it should stay in config.xml, but I can't find hook for this sales_qute_add_item in any of config XMLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK. In Magento is no default listener for this event. This event has been added by Magento core team specially for customization purposes.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_add_item>
        <observers>
            <your_observer_name>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>Your_Observer_Class</class>
                <method>yourObserverMethod</method>
            </your_observer_name>
        </observers>
      </sales_quote_add_item>
</events>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search all the config xml files for

```
<sales_quote_add_item>
```

If it is in a events tag then look at the method and class to see what file it is in.